# Remove padding in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, padding

I use `plt.subplots` to plot a list of images.

Here is my code:

```
m, n, c = output.shape 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
for i in range(4):
    ax[i].imshow(output[:,:,i].reshape(m, n, 1), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ax[i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[i].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.set_facecolor('red')
plt.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

How can I remove the red space on the left and right of the figure?

Comment: `None` often means *use the default*. So you might want `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=0, top=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)`

Comment: Make the figure narrower by passing figsize to the subplots call, or save it with bbox_inches=tight.

Comment: To remove the white space arround `imshow`, you need `imshow(..., aspect='auto')`